# assigned values to a field for all elements in an array of structs

Tags: c, struct

I have:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct DVD {
    char *movie_title;
    int minutes;
    float price;
};

void display_struct(struct DVD *ptr);

int
main()
{
    struct DVD movies[10];
    movies[0].movie_title = "I Am Legend"; //Don't want to do this
}

void
display_struct(struct DVD *ptr)
{
    printf("%s\n%i\n%f\n", ptr->movie_title, ptr->minutes, ptr->price);
}
```

I want to assigned 10 movie titles to my array of structs in a single statement. Is this possible? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a single statement like this?

```
main()
{
    struct DVD movies[10] = {
        { .movie_title = "I Am Legend",
          .minutes = 101,
          .price = 9.99
        },
        { .movie_title = "Hancock",
          .minutes = 103,
          .price = 5.99
        },
        { .movie_title = "MIB3",
          .minutes = 106,
          .price = 9.49
        }
    };
}
```

---

If you want to avoid all the field names:

```
main() {
    struct DVD movies[10] = {
        { "I Am Legend", 101, 9.99    },
        { "Hancock",     103, 5.99    },
        { "MIB3",        106, 9.49    }
    }; 
}
```

Comment: Note that the "dot-field-name =" is a relatively new addition to C.

if its not available on your compiler, you can just use the values without the field-names.

Comment: If you initialise in order, you don't even need the designators (and it works pre-C99).

Comment: If you like my answer, please "Accept" it by clicking the checkmark on the left-side. (below the Up-Vote/Down-Vote number)

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct DVD {
    char *movie_title;
    int minutes;
    float price;
};

void display_struct(struct DVD *ptr);

int main()
{
    struct DVD movies[10] =
    {
        { "I am Legend", 90, 4 },
        { "Star Wars", 100, 5 },
        { "Another Title", 60, 1},
        .......
    };
}

void display_struct(struct DVD *ptr)
{
    printf("%s\n%i\n%f\n", ptr->movie_title, ptr->minutes, ptr->price);
}
```